# When dropping page cache, who is releasing it?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, proc, cache, virtual-memory

When I run

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And Cached memory block is cleared, how can I tell who released that memory? Or is it releasing memory from no longer running processes?

Comment: The kernel has released the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` frees the page cache. This is kernel memory that contains the contents of disk blocks. This memory belongs to the kernel.

It's a bit misleading to describe it as “releasing” memory. The memory wasn't held in the first place: it's a cache. Cache pages are removed from memory if the memory is needed for a more important purpose. This is possible precisely because they aren't held — nobody needs them.

The *content* of the cache entries could belong to any number of processes. A memory page is often not owned by a single process. For example, if the page contains a cached page from a file, it could be said to belong to any of the processes that has the file open. But it could also be said to belong to the system as a whole, since the cache entry is useful even if no process currently has the file open.

Note that dropping the cache is pretty much only useful for one thing: to do I/O benchmarks with a pristine cache. Disk caches are vital to performance, and dropping them is a major performance hit (and so is not leaving enough room in RAM for caches, by the way).

Comment: So to add a bit of context, I am observing a bug with Docker behaviour. After some time it claims it's out of memory, even though there is free memory available, all memory is temporarily taken by the cache. After dropping the cache, the problem disappears for some time until the cache rebuilt. When observing /proc/meminfo again, only the cache figures change. I guess the memory release is not fast enough?

So after reading your answer, I am inclined to think that it might be not that simple to observe since the problem might be on Kernel it self and Docker just highlights that problem